# Simplification of expression through substitution

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

In the answers of the question I am solving, the following steps are shown:

$$-\frac{ie^{ou+6u}}{o+6}$$

Substitute $u=-ix$

$$\frac{ie^{6ix-iox}}{o+6}$$

I do not understand how substituting $-ix$ into the equation changed the exponent the way it did. Why did the minus sign in front of the fraction disappear and why is the exponent $6ix-iox$ instead of $-6ix-iox$?

Comment: There is a mistake in the answer given. You have the right answer.

Comment: Yeah, it looks wrong.